# Bubble Sorting Issue: Getting Exception In Main Thread

Tags: java

am a beginner to java. Help me here am trying to do BubbleSorting and am getting exception in the main method.Please tell me where is the mistake i have done here.

```
package Programs;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class EBubleSorting {

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the Size");
     int Size = in.nextInt();
     int [] array = new int[Size];
     int temp =0;
     System.out.println("Enter the elemnts of an Array");
     for (int i =0 ; i<Size ; i++)
     {
         array[i] = in.nextInt();
     }
     System.out.println("==============");
    // Bubble Sorting Starts 
     for (int ii =0 ; ii<Size ; ii++)
     {
        if(array[ii] > array[ii+1])
        {

            array[ii+1] = temp;
            System.out.println(array[ii+1]);
            array[ii+1] = array[ii];
            System.out.println(array[ii+1]);
            array[ii] = temp;
            System.out.println(array[ii]);
        }
        else if( array[ii] == array[ii+1]) 
        {

        }




     }


}


}
```

Comment: can you post your exception ?

Comment: What is your exception? Where is it coming from? Why do you think it's happening?

Comment: I think the 2nd for lop should be restricted to Size-1, otherwise in the last iteration you will hit an exception when you try to access array[ii+1]

Comment: This is the output on the console

Comment: Enter the Size
3
Enter the elemnts of an Array
3
1
2
==============
Exception in thread "main" 0
3
0
0
3
0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Programs.EBubleSorting.main(EBubleSorting.java:22)

Comment: am printing the out put just to check the process here... please ignore the println statments

Comment: Downvoted for: (1) stupid title (fixed) (2) no actual error message provided (3) see (1).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are indexed from 0 to (array.length-1). That's the first problem. 
If you want to bubble sort an array, here's a code that might help you.

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - j; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
 for (int ii =0 ; ii<Size ; ii++)
 {
    if(array[ii] > array[ii+1])
```

when `ii` is equal to `Size - 1` (the last item) then `array[ii+1]` will fail

if the array size is 4 as the data is

```
 array[0] = 2
 array[1] = 4
 array[2] = 3
 array[3] = 1
```

then when `ii` is 3 (the last item of the array), you can not access `array [3 + 1]` as this will be outside of the bounds of the array

Comment: I didnt get it still !!! can you please elaborate it

Comment: I have updated the answer for you